# First Android App Vexing Error

Tags: android, sdk

I just downloaded Android SDK 21 and I'm trying to follow their "Building Your First App" tutorial. I got fed up after it hadn't worked the fourth time around, and started just copy-pasting their code in for my own. However, when I go to emulate the program on my graphical layout, I keep getting the same error message, despite my literal pasting of their programming into my files. This is what I'm seeing:

Exception raised during rendering: java.lang.System.arraycopy([CI[CII)V
Couldn't resolve resource @string/edit_message
Couldn't resolve resource @string/button_send
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log

I am completely new to making Android Applications, and this is disheartening. What's going on here? How do I fix this? Thanks so much!

(I'm using Eclipse by the way)

Comment: vote up my answer and tick my answer so in future other also find that answer easily.thanks

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

Create a String resource file, with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="button_send">Send</string>
</resources>
```

#### Android Studio

If you use Android Studio, you should create a `res` folder next to your `java` folder, see:
[image: Android Studio Project Structure]

In that `res` folder, create a folder called `values`, and inside `values` a file called `strings.xml`. Copy the code from above into the file, and it should work.

#### Eclipse

In Eclipse, you should create your `res` folder next to your `src` folder.
Sorry, I don't use Eclipse, but you can read about the suggested project structure on the [Android Dev. Site](https://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your *strings.xml* file (*res/values* directory) doesn't contain `edit_message` and `button_send` resources or a *Project -> Clean...* is required.

Add something like this in that file inside `<resources>` element and then your layout XMLs will be able to reference the two strings by `@string/edit_message` and `@string/button_send`:

```
<string name="edit_message">Edit</string>
<string name="button_send">Send</string>
```

Comment: This is what my strings.xml file looks like right now:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My First App</string>
    <string name="edit_message">Enter a message</string>
    <string name="button_send">Send</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>
</resources>

Comment: @Zach: Try to _Project -> Clean..._ then.

Answer (score 0):

just create two lines in strings.xml and you find folder in the image i attached.[image]

```
<string name="edit_message ">Your Message</string>
<string name="button_send">Your Button Text</string>
```